# Бэкенд java. Связь с фронтендом. Сервер

Tags: java, сервер

Есть вопрос концептуального и общего характера.
Я не очень понимаю каким образом реализуется бэкенд на java. Есть, допустим, макет сайта сверстанный на HTML и СSS. В какой момент идет общение одного с другим?Объясните плз логику(хотя бы схематично, поэтапно) и инструменты. В какую сторону вообще копать.

Еще вопрос- есть десктопное приложение, к которому в общем-то понятно как прикруть БД с glassfish. Но, если предполагается сервер и разные клиенты, к примеру: веб, десктоп и мобильный.Я правильно понимаю, что для этого подразумевается, что мне(как один из вариантов по крайней мере) нужно арендовать хостинг и закинуть туда БД(если да, то в каком виде?как это реализуется?(схематично))И далее по мере работы с разными клиентами- кидать подключения к этой БД на арендованном хостинге?Т.е. серверная часть на том же хостинге?

Такая логика?:
Клиент(запрос)-> Хостинг:Сервер(обработка запроса)-> Хостинг: БД(результат запроса)-> Хостинг:Сервер(ответ)-> Клиент(результат)

P.s. Извиняюсь за возможный сумбур.Надеюсь понятная суть вопросов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Для того чтобы ответить на него Вам необходимо ознакомиться с платформой [Java EE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/index.html). После чего Вы сами сможете ответить на ваш вопрос. Можно конечно написать развернутый ответ, рассказать про архитектуру [Distributed Multitiered Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview003.htm#BNAAY), про технологии Java EE и т.д. Но я лучше приведу Вам ссылки:

---

1. [Официальная документация по Java Enterprise Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/index.html).
2. Книга [Beginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143024626X) (есть на русском).

---

Для связи HTML-страниц и java-кода в разные времена использовались разные инструменты. Начиналось все с [Java Servlet Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm#BNAFD), далее была [JavaServer Pages Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html). Эти технологии уже устарели и сейчас используется [JavaServer Faces Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro.htm#BNAPH).

---

***Схемы из книги Beginning Java EE 7***

**Структура веб-приложения**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Архитектура реального веб-приложения: интернет-магазин по продаже книг, дисков**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А могу я попросить не развернутый ответ тогда, а хотя бы просто схематично? Мне просто параллельно книге было значительно понятнее и удобнее двигаться по схеме. особенно, которую используют в реальных приложениях
P.s. Премного благодарен, за ссылки

Comment: @Montego, Вы хотите понять архитектуру (структуру, не знаю как понятнее) веб-приложения? Я привел ссылку на книгу (сам ее сейчас читаю), вот там все замечательно написано, с примерами + автор на протяжении книги разрабатывает интернет-магазин по продаже книг и дисков. Очень советую почитать! P.S. Я добавил несколько схем из книги.

Comment: "Вы хотите понять архитектуру (структуру, не знаю как понятнее) веб-приложения"  - да, да, именно структуру.   Спасибо еще раз за ссылку на книгу, вчера начал читать тоже:)

Answer (score 4):

Я не спец по бэкенду так что, могу ошибаться во многом.
Начнем по порядку, во первых если брать пример обычного сайта HTML + CSS, то не очень разумно писать бэкенд на java,
что бы просто отдавать статические ресурсы. Должна быть какая то бизнес логика, так что можно взять к примеру
интернет магазин HTML + CSS + JavaScript.
На счет инструментов, есть разные подходы по написанию, но допустим мы возьмем устаревший класический стэк JavaEE - это JSP, Servlets,
Filters, и вэбконтейнер Tomcat, в котором все это будет крутиться. Декомпозируем HTML в JSP.
Запросы обрабатывают наши сервлеты, то есть клиент шлет запрос на главную страничку например, запрос ловит фильтр и проверяет к примеру залогинен
ли пользователь и тд, отдает с результатом проверки сервлету, а сервлет на основании результата обрабатывет что то, и отдает то, что нужно.
Еще некоторое общение с сервером реализуется с помощью AJAX запросов, что бы не перезагружать полность страницу.

На счет хостингов и разных клиентов, вопрос обширный, и реализация бэкенда может быть разной, в зависимости от поставленых задач. Например мобильному клиенту лучше общаться с REST сервисом, запрос-ответ в формате JSON, если это моб. приложение например. Java хостинг относительно дорогой, но есть фишки типа серверов Amazon`а, там где предоставляют по моему год бесплатного хостинга, за это время проэкт либо стрельнет либо нет=( И тебе никто не будет обьяснять схематично или как то по другому, каким образом заливать БД и Серверную часть на хостинг и тд, по этому поводу могу по рекомендовать отличную, но платную платформу по Java, там имеются уроки от начальных и до Spring, Hibernet технологий и соответственно всех вопросов, по поводу java хостинга! Это не реклама, если есть желание, то напиши maxim07070711@gmail.com, дам ссылку.

И напоследок плюсую ответ выше, что бы понять как работает вся система, нужно учить JavaEE, и все станет на свои места!

Comment: Премного благодарен за развернутый ответ!Видимо лучше действительно начать книгу сначала и потом уже по мере задавать вопросы. Сейчас отпишусь по поводу ресурса